# Счетность множеств

Tags: математика, множества

Самый известный способ доказательства несчетности множества действительных чисел - канторов диагональный процесс. Если мы применим аналогичную процедуру для множества рациональных чисел(каждое число мы можем представить в виде бесконечного : 0.1 = 0.1000000...) то, соответственно,получим результат, что оно также несчетно, хотя мы знаем, что это утверждение неверно и множество рациональных чисел можно посчитать. Подозреваю, что ошибка в том, что нельзя применять канторов диагональный метоl для рациональных чисел, но почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что все рациональные числа - периодические дроби...  А вы получите в результате непериодическую дробь, т.е. ни с одним из рациональных чисел у вас не будет совпадать **иррациональное** (не рациональное!) число. Что, увы, доказывает только существование иррациональных чисел, и ничего более.

А доказать счетность рациональных чисел очень просто - расположить все первые в первом ряду, вторые (n/2) во втором и так далее, а потом просто пройтись по ним эдакой лесенкой...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вообще - вы же должны знать, как справиться администратору гостиницы с бесконечным числом номеров, из которых все заполнены, когда прибывает бесконечное количество бесконечных групп туристов? :)

Comment: Доказательство счетности мне понятно и в нем все логично, но ведь если мы применим канторов диагональный процесс для рациональных чисел, то наткнемся на противоречие, вот в чем проблема для меня

Comment: Потому что вы получите непериодическое *действительное* число, которое не совпадает ни с одним из ваших рациональных чисел. И что вы этим докажете? Что существуют иррациональные числа? Мы и так это знаем... Что мощность множества рациональных чисел меньше мощности действительных, только и всего...

Comment: Почему не совпадает? 0.1 к примеру, является рациональным числом, а множество рациональных чисел является подмножеством действительных, следовательно мы можем представить его в виде 0.100000... . То есть каждое рациональное число у нас априори является действительным.

Comment: Да, но не каждое действительное - рациональное! А вы, применяя канторов метод, получите действительное (не рациональное!) число. Что ничего не доказывает. Получите таким методом **рациональное число**, не совпадающее ни с одним рациональным числом - тогда и поговорим :)

Comment: Вы никак не хотите понять... Идея доказательства Кантора - в противоречии: получении числа, которое  и входит в множество, и не входит. Вы же получаете число, которое просто не входит во множество рациональных чисел, только и всего. С чего вы решили, что число, у которого первая цифра не совпадает с первой цифрой первого числа, вторая - со второй цифрой второго - и тд и тп - **рациональное**? Это просто иррациональное число, которое, понятно, не входит во множество всех рациональных чисел...

Comment: Ну возьмем тогда к примеру числа 0.1, 0.2,0.3, 0.4, 0.5. С помощью канторова диагонального процесса получим 0.21111, которое будет являться рациональным числом. Я понимаю, что в данном случае я привел конечную последовательность, но ведь аналогичную процедуру можно сделать и для бесконечной и при чем для рациональных чисел и в результате получится рациональное число, которое не будет посчитано.

Comment: Ну с чего вы решили, что, продляя процесс до бесконечности, вы получите **рациональное** число?

Comment: А почему нет? Ведь мы его все равно сможем записать в виде дроби

Comment: Вот вам простенький пример - берем все целые числа и доказываем канторовым способом их несчетность. Получаем, скажем, 1.1111111111111 - число, которого, очевидно, нет среди наших **целых** чисел. Но оно-то само **целым не является**!

Comment: Так, все. Как запишете - приходите, поговорим. Только ни хрена у вас не получится - потому что это будет иррациональное число, дробью не записываемое... На этом, простите, дискуссию заканчиваю. Все, что мог, разжевал и написал. Может, у кого-то получится лучше :) Для простоты ограничьтесь целыми числами и покажите методом Кантора целое число, которого нет среди целых чисел...

Comment: Ну вы подкинули мысль касательно того, что число не будет рациональным, правда, как это доказать, мне не понятно. Тем не менее хоть немного я теперь в этом вопросе продвинулся.

Comment: И то, что это работает для целых чисел не говорит о том, что это не работает для рациональных

Comment: "Подкинул мысль"?? Да я разжевываю это битый час!...

Comment: Ну в последнем пунктике вы галочку не поставили. Докажите, что число, полученное канторовым диагональным процессом над рациональными числами не рациональное, и тогда я с вами соглашусь.

Comment: Потому что множество рациональных чисел счетно. Потому что оно не совпадает ни с одним из рациональных чисел (а вы выписали их все) - значит, оно уже иррационально, потому что  множество действительных чисел включает как рациональные, так и иррациональные числа. Не все числа, записываемые в виде бесконечной десятичной дроби, рациональные. Все, хватит заниматься демагогией.

Comment: Вот, это действительно то, что я хотел, спасибо за то, что потратили на меня столько времени, просто этот вопрос не давал мне спать несколько дней))

Comment: Ну если ответ устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый...